# ReactJs add class to this button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have multiple buttons on a page, when user click on each button it should show a loading, I do this with a `class`, but there is a problem, it add loading to all button but I just need to add class to `this` button *(which is clicked not all!)*

You can see a simple demo **[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/kycdgzv3/)**

```
handleClick = (e) => {
    this.setState({
  loading: 'loading'
  })
}
```

I am aware that all buttons use the same `state` but how can I use changed `state` on clicked button not all. what is the best practice?
should I use `ref` ? or should I use multiple states? 
but I don't know how many buttons will be add on this page in the future. any idea to give a solution or trick.

Comment: This can be one of the option https://jsfiddle.net/cm28rdo6/

Comment: @ankitkanojia yes, good but it won't work if you click on all buttons, for example click on the first button, then second, it just show loading on a single button

Comment: You're right, please see Modify version here https://jsfiddle.net/cm28rdo6/1/

Comment: I think not even required loading state, as you pass the event on button click so you just need to add the class name in existing clicked object.

Comment: Because when it show loading, it post something on `api` and when it give success, loading should remove, but this happen on other function, not handleClick, so how can I select that button for remove loading class? @ankitkanojia

Comment: try this https://jsfiddle.net/wLp83rec/ in case of you want to remove loading on API response then you need to simply call a function this.removeLoading('btn1') | this.removeLoading('btn2') | this.removeLoading('btn3') accordingly

Comment: @ankitkanojia it can be a solution, please make it as answer. but as I said in my question, `I don't know how many buttons will be add on this page in future`

Comment: please review this example, https://jsfiddle.net/61fpb524/1/  the dynamic example with API as well. verify it and in case of still required any chnages  please do let me know

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205129/discussion-between-ankitkanojia-and-tour-travel).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Here is the dynamic button binding with handled click event separately, Even added Axios API call so that in API response you can remove loading on that button as well.**

Here is a working [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/go9y80j3/)

```js
const {
    Button
} = semanticUIReact


class App extends React.Component {

    handleClick = (name) => {
        this.refs[name].ref.classList.add('loading');
        axios.get('https://simonbreiter.com/wp-json/wp/v2/projects?_embed')
            .then(response => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    this.removeLoading(name)
                }, 3000)
            })
            .catch(error => console.log(error));
    }

    removeLoading = (name) => {
        this.refs[name].ref.classList.remove('loading');
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {[...Array(3)].map((data, index) => {
                    const btnIndex = index + 1;
                    return <Button ref={"btn" + btnIndex} className={'btn'} onClick={() => this.handleClick("btn" + btnIndex)}>Button {btnIndex}</Button>
                })}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.1/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.1/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui-react/0.81.2/semantic-ui-react.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.3.2/semantic.min.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios@0.15.3/dist/axios.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: What about `React.createRef()`? I think OP didn't try your code at all, just feel this right!

Comment: @Pedram React.createRef() is the bind method that can be defined in the constructor but with this example, we just required to toggle class so we can use them directly rather than initialize reference. We can follow either option. Both are equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily get the selected `button` using your handleClick method. And then toggle the `loading` class. Here is a working [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/a8t1oz6j/1/)

```
const {
  Button
} = semanticUIReact


class App extends React.Component {


handleClick = (e) => {
  // You can use .add or .toggle according to your requirement.
  e.target.classList.toggle('loading');
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
       <Button className='btn' onClick={this.handleClick}>Button 1</Button>
       <Button className='btn' onClick={this.handleClick}>Button 2</Button>
       <Button className='btn' onClick={this.handleClick}>Button 3</Button>
    </div>
  )
}
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: Oh, i get it now. You can easily add a remove class method when you receive a response from server

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding to this question, the better approach is to handle/maintain state of such generic component to it's own component level. I have prepared one example on the basis of the code provided by you.
https://jsfiddle.net/y0cjbodq/

```js
const {
    Button
} = semanticUIReact

class ButtonComp extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            loading: false
        }
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }


    handleClick(e) {
        this.setState({
            loading: !this.state.loading
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Button className={'btn ' + (this.state.loading ? 'loading' : null)} onClick={this.handleClick}>Button 1</Button>
        )
    }
}

class App extends React.Component {
    // Moved state management to component level
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <ButtonComp />
                <ButtonComp />
                <ButtonComp />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.1/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.1/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui-react/0.81.2/semantic-ui-react.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.3.2/semantic.min.css"/>

<div id="app"></app>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create an array of buttons. Then you can compare selected index with iteration index and can apply loading class.

```js
const {
    Button
} = semanticUIReact

class App extends React.Component {

    state = {
        clickedBtnIndex: -1,
    }

    buttons = ["Button 1", "Button 2", "Button 3"];

    handleClick = (i) => {
        this.setState({
            clickedBtnIndex: i
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {
                    this.buttons.map((btn, i) =>
                        <Button className={'btn ' + (i === this.state.clickedBtnIndex ? "loading" : "")} onClick={() => this.handleClick(i)}>
                            {btn}
                        </Button>
                    )
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.1/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.1/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui-react/0.81.2/semantic-ui-react.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.3.2/semantic.min.css" />

<div id="app"></div>
```